# creating new record always null firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase 4.12.0 and I am trying to get the value of a `database.Reference` object.

I do the following:

```
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + 'collaboration_songs');
    var newCollab = ref.push();
    newCollab.set({songs: {}});
    var id = newCollab.key();
    console.log("added record with id " + id);
    ref.child(id).once("value").then(function(data){
      var val = data.val();
      console.log(val, ' why is this null');
    });
```

I know it created the key because i have the key logged and it looks legit. The data, I can't read. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reading anything because you're not actually writing anything.  With this bit of code:

```
newCollab.set({songs: {}});
```

The server writes nothing, because there are no values behind any of the keys.  If a key has no values, it simply doesn't exist in Realtime Database.  An empty object, like the on you're passing, have no keys or values.  Also, the random push id that's generated is actually generated on the client, on the server, so even if it looks "legit", that doesn't mean the server did anything.

Why don't you try writing an actual value instead?

```
newCollab.set({songs: "an actual value"});
```

Also, you should check the value in Firebase console to make sure it actually wrote what you expected.

Comment: I see, how can I have the "an actual value" be a generated key for a child of newCollab.child("songs") when "songs" does not exist yet, and therefore i ostensibly can't do `.push()` yet?

Comment: No, you can push.  It just generates a unique key under which you can set more keys and values.  The keys just won't exist if there's not a value behind them.